# How to fix the errors I get when migrating from WordPress 4?

Tags: migrations

On a fresh Drupal 8 installation, I installed the [WP Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/wp_migrate) module. I downloaded a snapshot of the WordPress database on my local machine, edited the `settings.php` file, and added the following after the default database:

```
$databases['migrate']['default'] = array (
  'database' => 'mylocaldb',
  'username' => 'root',
  'password' => 'root',
  'prefix'  => 'myprefix_',
  'host' => '127.0.0.1',
  'port' => '8889',
  'namespace' => 'Drupal\\Core\\Database\\Driver\\mysql',
  'driver' => 'mysql',
);
```

When I run `drush migrate-manifest modules/migrate_wordpress/manifest_wordpress.yml --legacy-db-url=/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql://dbuser:dbpwd@127.0.0.1/dbname --legacy-db-prefix=mywpprefix_ -vvv`, I get the following error:

> Undefined offset: 4 Database.php:212
>   Undefined index: source NoSourcePluginDecorator.php:39
>   Undefined index: driver Database.php:364
>   Driver not specified for this database connection: migrate

On another Drupal 8 installation, I installed the [WordPress Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/wordpress_migrate) module. While I was able to upload XML files, the module is still not ready and it does not migrate paths and categories.

How do I fix those errors?